# I want to remove comma between two double quote and allowed space between two double quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I have one search string like txtKeyword and it will accept all the below case for highlighting skills

```
1.C# JAVA
2."C#" AND "JAVA"
5.C# "JAVA"
6.C#,'JAVA'
7.C#,"JAVA"
8.C#,"JAVA",'PHP'
9.C#,"JAVA" AND PHP
```

In all above case C# and JAVA are highlighted..but for

```
"MY SQL","SQL SERVER"
```

it will not highlight MY SQL and SQL SERVER because of space between two double quote

so final array is like `["MY,SQL,SQL,SERVER"]`

But i need final array like `["MY SQL,SQL SERVER,C#,Java"]`

Question in logical terms-
 I want to remove comma between two double quote and allowed space between two double quote,and remove all spaces outside two double quote and split array with comma

Here is my code snippet

```
//Grab basic search string on resume result list
var grabBasicSearchKeyword = $("#txtKeyword").val();

if (grabBasicSearchKeyword!=null)
{
    //Remove Unnecessary Characters From Basic Search String
    var finalBasicSearchString = grabBasicSearchKeyword.replace(/[`~!@$%^&*()_|\-=?;:'"<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');

    //Check And Remove: "OR","AND","NOT","or","and" & "not" From Basic Search String
    if (finalBasicSearchString.indexOf('OR') || finalBasicSearchString.indexOf('AND') || finalBasicSearchString.indexOf('NOT') || finalBasicSearchString.indexOf('or') || finalBasicSearchString.indexOf('and') || finalBasicSearchString.indexOf('not'))
    {
        var findOR = finalBasicSearchString.replace(/OR/g, ' ');
        var findor = findOR.replace(/or/g, ' ');

        var findAND = findor.replace(/AND/g, ' ');
        var findand = findAND.replace(/and/g, ' ');

        var findNOT = findand.replace(/NOT/g, ' ');
        var findnot = findNOT.replace(/not/g, ' ');

        var removeDoubleQuote = findnot.replace(/"/g, '');
        var removeBackSlash = removeDoubleQuote.replace(/\\/g, '');
        var removeComma = removeBackSlash.replace(/,/g, ' ');
        var finalArray = removeComma.split(" ");

        for (var j = 0; j < finalArray.length; j++) {
            if (masterSkillArray.contains(finalArray[j])) {
                basicSearchHighlightArray.push(finalArray[j]);
            }
        }
        $(".skil-list").highlight(basicSearchHighlightArray);
        $(".post").highlight(basicSearchHighlightArray);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, could you edit a little your examples to make your post more understandable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the 'ignore case' flag `i` for your logical operator patterns to cut down on the duplicate regexing.

You can do all of the logical replacements in a single regex - `/\b(?:OR|AND|NOT)\b/gi` (the i flag making the matches case insensitive).

You'll need to treat quoted strings separately.  In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vD58d/9/) the quoted strings are matched and used to create a new string with only those terms.  A second new string is then created by removing the quoted strings from the original input (as well as commas).  The strings are then appended and split on `,`.

As shown by the fiddle, rather than creating several variables, you can simply chain your replacements.

Comment: .replace(/","|"\\s"/g, '\"\"') & .join() not working..can you please..show me in example..that how exactly its going to work..

Comment: My apologies, the double quotes don't need escaping:  `s = s.replace(/","|"\s"/g, '""');` will do what I think you wanted it to do.  This means you won't be able to split on a space anymore; if you still want to split, then use `'"<your_split_char>"'` as your replacement text.

Comment: Ahhh, I believe I've misunderstood what you were after.  You want to remove any commas within the quoted strings but keep them as your split character?  So `"MY, SQL","SQL SERVER"` -> `"MY SQL","SQL SERVER"`?  I'll update my answer later today if this is the case.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vD58d/5/) to see whether this is what you're looking for. If it is, then you'll have to surround each term with quotation marks if they don't already have them, then remove them all right before you split, otherwise things like "A B" C "D E" will cause problems for your regex.

Comment: Hi ! you are almost near to my question can you please edit fiddle for s= "A B" C "D E" ..i m trying to do but it doesn't work

Comment: My orginoal string like s= "SQL SERVER" , JAVA and i need array like ["SQL SERVER,JAVA"] without any space except for double quote..means "JAVA PHP" is one word for me JAVA PHP because its comes under double quote

Comment: That complicates things a little, but this seems to do the job as long as you don't need to maintain the order - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vD58d/9/).  If you need to maintain the ordering then your job gets much more difficult.  You'll likely need to tokenize, loop through and if a token begins with `"` keep appending tokens until one ends with `"`.